# Populating a JTable with an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I am trying to make a table with multiple corresponding arrays filling in the information vertically. If each of my arrays only had 3 pieces of data, the below code would work perfectly:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableSample {

    static String[] itemArray = new String[] {"item1","item2","item3"};
    static String[] conditionArray = new String[] {"condition1","condition2","condition3"};
    static String[] locationArray = new String[] {"location1","location2","location3"};

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("JTable Sample");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();

    Object rows[][] = { { itemArray[0], conditionArray[0], locationArray[0] },
            { itemArray[1], conditionArray[1], locationArray[1] },
            { itemArray[2], conditionArray[2], locationArray[2] } };

    Object columns[] = { "Symbol", "Name", "Price" };
    JTable table = new JTable(rows, columns);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    content.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
       f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

However, each of my arrays has 10,000 lines, which would be extremely impractical to continue filling out these lines 9,997 more times. I would like to create a loop something like this: (does not work, but you get the idea of what i'm trying to accomplish)

```
for(int i=0;i<itemArray.length;i++)
    {
        Object rows[][]={
                { itemArray[i], conditionArray[i], locationArray[i] }};

    }
```

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` might be able to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the data to the `DefaultTableModel` using the `addRow()` method:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

for(int i=0;i<itemArray.length;i++)
{
    Vector row = new Vector(3);
    row.add( itemArray[i] );
    row.add( conditionArray[i] );
    row.add( locationArray[i] );
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Cannot find symbol- class DefaultTableModel"

Comment: Read the API. It will tell you what package the DefaultTableModel belongs to so you can import the package. This is basic programming and problem solving.

Comment: nevermind yet again. (0,itemArray.length) gives me the correct rows and columns

Comment: ok, this is awesome, thank you. my only problem is that columns are labled A, B, C. how can i customize the names?

Comment: @Blaine, You specified the column names array in your original question. Read the API for the various constructors you can use with the DefaultTableModel. When you are introduced to a new class take the time to read the API to better understand how it works.